# New xcode 8 changes everything to fileprivate

Tags: swift3

I updated my project in Swift for iOS 10 to latest Xcode 8 and it changes all my private properties to fileprivate.

before:

```
private var firstname: String
```

Now:

```
fileprivate var firstname: String
```

I tried it still works if I change it back to private. Should I use fileprivate or private?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift 3, `fileprivate` is the new `private`. So you can keep `fileprivate` and everything should work as before.